# How to access sar command info from file in linux

Tags: linux, sar

I'm trying to collect system activity using sar command in Linux. I can get this info readily by executing sar command from shell. Internally this information is popped from some file in /var/log/sa/sadd. but it contains values updated every 10min. I need to collect system activity at every second (sar -A 1). If I need to read this info from internal file every second, is it possible.

Cheers.

Comment: the sar package comes with a monitor and init startup scripts. Does your system have a man page for sadm?

Comment: I'm able to obtain this info from /proc filesystem. 'sar', 'vmstat' rely on /proc and extract information from there.

Comment: yes. you need to collect the information over a long period of time and maintain it in a database without losing it to other users.